# Undeclared identifier 'DISPATCH_QUEUE­_PRIORITY_DEFAULT'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, dispatch

I defined this:

```
#define kQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE­_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kJSONUrl [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=403704786354846&format=json"]
```

and in the viewDidLoad:

```
dispatch_async(kQueue, ^{
    ...
});
```

but i get:

```
undeclared identifier "DISPATCH QUEUE­ PRIORITY DEFAULT"
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: You have some strange, non-visible typo in `DISPATCH_QUEUE­_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`. It should be `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`. I know they look the same but the 1st (yours) doesn't work and the 2nd one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo issue... There's an invisible character (it's a [soft hyphen](http://graphemica.com/00AD)) between `QUEUE` and `_`

When I copy/paste your `DISPATCH_QUEUE­_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` in a browser, here's the Google's result :

```
https://www.google.fr/search?q=DISPATCH_QUEUE%C2%AD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT&etc...
```

Comment: Probably he didn't define it himself, but copied it from some website.